# Is there any way to build a fence without putting posts in the ground?

Tags: walls, fence

I want to build a nice looking wooden fence around my property.  However part of it has dirt, part of it has concrete. Also, there are already block walls between my two neighbors. I don't want to screw into my neighbor's block wall fence to install my wooden fence.

Can I build a fence without putting posts in the ground? Can I pour some concrete footings that sit above ground and posts go into that?  The footings could make so that it looks decorative.

Is there any reason that I should not do this from a safety perspective?
We obviously don't want it to topple over. The footings can be made so that the shape is stable...i.e. it is wider at the bottom.

Comment: Wind is the issue and wind on a fence makes a LOT of force. Footings would need to be VERY LARGE and heavy. There are metal fittings for this though like this one.. Don't know where you live, but you may be able to find something similar. http://www.homedepot.com/p/Simpson-Strong-Tie-12-Gauge-Black-Powder-Coated-E-Z-Base-FPBB44/100655350

Comment: Thirty years ago a homeowner in our neighborhood built a tall, double planked fence. It is board-on-board on both sides of the posts. The guy who built it is long gone, but the fence remains, now decaying. Some dogs show a lot of interest in that fence and one dog owner said his dog is acting like there are squirrels living inside the fence. I think it is more likely rats. If you build a fence right next to another fence, you will create an inaccessible space for unwanted animals to live in.

Comment: Thanks @JimStewart.  I didn't consider that. Maybe I'll think of a design that will prevent this. There must be ways around it.